# DICOM: relating Slice Location to Image Orientation and Patient Position

Tags: dicom

If the Image Orientation (Patient) tag (0020,0037) reads [1,0,0,0,1,0] and the Patient Position tag (0018, 5100) reads ‘HFS’, how do I interpret Slice Location tag (0020,1041), assuming that it exists? 
I know that it represents the `Relative position of the image plane in millimeters', I'm just having trouble relating the end points of the range to the Z axis in the DICOM Reference Coordinates System (RCS).

**Example:** I have an sequence of Slice Location numbers in the range: [-1873.382, -771.782]

Since the numbers are increasing and in the DICOM RCS, the Z axis increases in the Inferior to Superior direction, can I conclude that '-1873.382' is the position of the most Inferior slice?

Also, just to note that the z coordinate of my Image Position (Patient) (0020,0032) attribute for each slice, contains the same information as my Slice Location tag.

Comment: You will also need Image Position (Patient) tag 0020,0032) to order your stack.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40008507/how-to-spatially-order-files-in-a-dicom-data-sequence/40014740#40014740

Comment: @LEADTOOLSSupport I noticed that the z coordinate of the Image Position (Patient) tag contained the same information as the Slice Location, so since it didn't contain any new (relevant) information, I didn't mention it in my post. But for clarification, I edited my post to add this.

Comment: @kritzel_sw Thanks - I read the information in those links after my original post but I still have some confusion. I edited my above post to add more information.

Comment: @user762098: See my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Image Position (Patient) (0020, 0032) is the x, y, and z coordinates of the upper left hand corner of the image and Image Orientation (0020, 0037) says the direction of the first row and the first column with respect patient (farther  defined by patient orientation). X-axis increasing direction is towards the left hand side of the patient, y-axis increasing is towards the posterior side and z-axis increasing is toward the head of the patient.

In your case, if the Z axis is changing and increase is towards the head, I would use the Z-axis values for sorting the stack. It is more reliable than Slice Location. Yes the smallest value (e.g. value  -1873.382) is the most Inferior slice.

Answer (score 9):

I still advise against using the Slice Location attribute for sorting. In MR imaging, slices can have arbitrary orientation and even in CT the gantry can be tilted, so you cannot rely that all slices are parallel to the xy-plane. So you actually do not know to which axis the Slice Location refers.

What I do is to subtract ImagePositionPatient from two slices which gives me the direction in which the slices in the stack are moving. Ordering can be done by the amount of the difference vectors.

Comment: This answer is half way correct.  You should subtract any two IPP and normalize to get the vector A however you should take the cross product of the IOP to get the direction. The IOP has two vectors (row, col) and B = row x col. If the angle between A, B is more than 180, then reverse A. The angle between A and B is the Gantry Tilt, and A is the axis you should use to sort the slice locations.

Comment: The DICOM refers to SliceLocation as a "nominal" value. it other words it is not reliable in any mathematical sense.  Use the IPP instead.

Comment: Correction: I meant to say  "if the angle between A and B is more than 90 degrees"  and by the way. All the IPP in the series are supposed to be collinear. If they aren't then, well... you're in la la land.  Also if the distance between to IPP is less than 1e-7 (float epsilon) then you are also kinda screwed.